# XPath expression to create text delimited string

Tags: xml, xpath, eval, csv

**Edit:** Appears that my software only supports XPath 1.0. :(

I need to create a delimited string of the following format:

`Stuff,Things;A,1;B,2`

From the following XML Data:

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
 <Row>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Stuff</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Things</Data></Cell>
 </Row>
 <Row>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
 </Row>
 <Row>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data></Cell>
 </Row>
</Table>
```

Columns are denoted by `,` and rows are denoted by `;`. This should create a two dimensional array.

**---------Notes-----------**

I have tried the following expression against the sample XML but it does not work when applied using NotePad++ XPatherizerNPP:

`eval(eval(Row, 'concat(Cell, ";")'), "..")`

The above expression throws the following erorr: `XSLTContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function`

The "Eval" function typically works in MS InfoPath, but it is possible that XPatherizer does not handle the XPath in the same way that InfoPath does. It is also possible that I don't understand the context of this statement and I am using it inappropriately.

As a sidenote, are there any good web resources that explain the use of XPath Eval? I don't fully understand it and cannot seem to find any good explanations.

**--------Full XML--------**

Here is the full body of the XML I am trying to use. It is an "XML Spreadsheet" generated by MS Excel. I do not have the ability to create a custom XML mapping as I do not have the rights to install the XML Tools on my system.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Smith, Robert;-</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Smith, Robert;-</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2013-08-27T16:29:45Z</Created>
  <Company>SmithWorks</Company>
  <Version>14.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>10035</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>22035</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>240</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>90</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Stuff</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Things</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>3</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>1</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet3">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: I've recently updated XPatherizer NPP to the Unicode version of NP++. There is a github project for it here: [https://github.com/shrout1/xpatherizernpp](https://github.com/shrout1/xpatherizernpp)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a magic for me but I tried this

```
string-join((for $n in //Row return string-join($n/Cell, ',')), ';')
```

and its result is what you need

```
Stuff,Things;A,1;B,2
```

Edit: I forgot mention this will work only in xpath 2.0

Comment: Hey! That works great on [this page](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) but I seem to get an "Invalid Token" error. I adjusted the expression to the following escaped format, but it didn't seem to fix it: `string-join((for $n in //Row return string-join($n/Cell, &apos;,&apos;)), &apos;;&apos;)` Thanks again!

Comment: I meant to say it worked great on the page specified above but the invalid token error occurs when I use it elsewhere :)

Comment: Could you pls specify "elsewhere" in more details? :)

Comment: I have tried in XPatherizerNPP 2.10 with NotePad++ and also a "Query XPath" tool in Nintex Workflow 2010 (I will be using this statement to pull nodes from an excel file and push them into a database as a string using Nintex Workflow). Does XPatherizerNPP support XPath 2.0?

Comment: Sadly it appears my software only supports XPath 1.0... Ugh... I wish I could upvote you more than once! If only I had access to XPath 2.0...